# Bokeh Clustered bar chart

Tags: python, bokeh

[image]I have some data:

```py
data = {'FFCB' : ['D','I'],
        'CS'   : [0.966248, 0],
        'FPSI'   : [0.00264871, 0],
        'SA'   : [0, 0.114216],
        'NA'   : [0.0127895, 0.00567031],
        'O'   : [0.00552444, 0],
        'FPSDA'   : [0.00136219, 0],
        'HDR'   : [3.78387e-05, 0]}
```

I would like to create a **clustered** bar chart in `bokeh`, such that the value of the bar and its `x` label is  shown in the tooltip. Also the xaxis major label should be shown in the legend. xaxis major label is not shown. Only the group label is shown. xaxis subgroup label are the label values (`'D'`,`'I'`). xaxis major label are the balance labels. `('CS','FPSI','SA','NA','O','FPSDA','HDR')`. The major lables need to be shown on the legend since they are long in the real data (As shown in the image). The value of the bar should be shown in the tooltip.

Would anyone be able help me on this matter. Please see image.

Thanks

Michael

Comment: Your question is not clear: what is the difference between **xaxis_major_label** and **major_xaxis_label** ? What is the **xaxis_group_label** ? Should it be shown in the tooltip or in the legend? Why are you writing them with underscores like there were the Bokeh vbar attributes? what are **balance column headers**? Maybe you could create a mockup how it should look like?

Comment: edited some words. Thanks

Comment: Added image of mockup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job (tested for Bokeh v1.0.4). You can change the legend orientation to "vertical" if you like.

```
from bokeh.core.properties import value
from bokeh.io import show, output_file
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool, CustomJS
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.transform import dodge
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral6

data = {'FFCB' : ['D', 'I'],
        'CS'   : [0.013254, 0.01],
        'FPSI'   : [0.00264871, 0.02],
        'SA'   : [0.03, 0.114216],
        'NA'   : [0.0127895, 0.00567031],
        'O'   : [0.00552444, 0.03],
        'FPSDA'   : [0.00136219, 0.04],
        'HDR'   : [0.03, 0.05]}

source = ColumnDataSource(data = data)

p = figure(x_range = data['FFCB'], y_range = (0, 0.2), plot_width = 600, plot_height = 400, title = "Clustered bar chart", tools = '')

vbar1 = p.vbar(x = dodge('FFCB', -0.25, range = p.x_range), top = 'CS', width = 0.1, source = source,
       color = Spectral6[0], legend = value("CS"))
hover_tool_vbar1 = HoverTool(tooltips = [('CS', '@CS{0.000}')], show_arrow = False, renderers = [vbar1])

vbar2 = p.vbar(x = dodge('FFCB', -0.15, range = p.x_range), top = 'FPSI', width = 0.1, source = source,
       color = Spectral6[1], legend = value("FPSI"))
hover_tool_vbar2 = HoverTool(tooltips = [('FPSI', '@FPSI{0.000}')], show_arrow = False, renderers = [vbar2])

vbar3 = p.vbar(x = dodge('FFCB', -0.05, range = p.x_range), top = 'SA', width = 0.1, source = source,
       color = Spectral6[2], legend = value("SA"))
hover_tool_vbar3 = HoverTool(tooltips = [('SA', '@SA{0.000}')], show_arrow = False, renderers = [vbar3])

vbar4 = p.vbar(x = dodge('FFCB', 0.05, range = p.x_range), top = 'NA', width = 0.1, source = source,
       color = Spectral6[3], legend = value("NA"))
hover_tool_vbar4 = HoverTool(tooltips = [('NA', '@NA{0.000}')], show_arrow = False, renderers = [vbar4])

vbar5 = p.vbar(x = dodge('FFCB', 0.15, range = p.x_range), top = 'O', width = 0.1, source = source,
       color = Spectral6[4], legend = value("O"))
hover_tool_vbar5 = HoverTool(tooltips = [('O', '@O{0.000}')], show_arrow = False, renderers = [vbar5])

vbar6 = p.vbar(x = dodge('FFCB', 0.25, range = p.x_range), top = 'HDR', width = 0.1, source = source,
       color = Spectral6[5], legend = value("HDR"))
hover_tool_vbar6 = HoverTool(tooltips = [('HDR', '@HDR{0.000}')], show_arrow = False, renderers = [vbar6])

p.x_range.range_padding = 0.2
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.legend.location = "top_left"
p.legend.click_policy = 'hide'
p.legend.orientation = "horizontal"

p.add_tools(hover_tool_vbar1, hover_tool_vbar2, hover_tool_vbar3, hover_tool_vbar4, hover_tool_vbar5, hover_tool_vbar6)

show(p)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Ok. Thanks alot.